# Issues with VB6 FDFToolkit on a VB6 (not .net) application

Tags: vba, vb6, fdf

Started a new job where I'm working on all sorts of legacy apps - I came across one which is a VB6 (not .net) one. Its using Adobes old FDFtoolkit (again, not the one found at fdftoolkit.net) which can only be registered on a server.

Problem is, sometime over the past few years the FDF to PDF converter stopped working. 
My issue, I'm pretty sure its a .dll issue - on the server FDFTK.dll and FDFACX.dll are in the Windows/SysWOW64 folder.

I don't know if their location is incoherent with where the legacy application is looking. When I'm in Visual Basic 6 (the IDE) it looks for references in the Windows\system32 folder.

Any thoughts? I ask because I don't have direct access to the server so its slow going to 'guess and check' lots of options.

**EDIT:** Also the server holding the .dll is a windows server 2003 (however the server passing it the fdf is a windows server 2008)

Its like a puzzle!

Comment: Since you didn't mention getting an error I am assuming it's a silent failure. Have you looked at the events log for an error. Try using Process Monitor to see what is being accessed.

Comment: Another problem, this app doesn't work with anything but old IE. Which doesn't have good dev tools, so I'm not sure if there is a failed 'GET' or anything else.

Answer (score 0):

On 64 bit systems Windows secretly redirects calls of 32 bit programs from system32 to syswow64.

VB6 is 32 bit, everything needs to be 32 bit.

The only thing you can really do is reregister the dll. Most but not all com dlls self register.

Note using 32 bit tools.

```
c:\windows\syswow64\regsvr32 c:\windows\syswow64\dllname.dll
```

Comment: Thanks! I tried it and I'm getting a "myDll.dll was loaded, but the DllRgisterServer entry point was not found. DllregisterServer may not be exported, or a corrupt version of ./.../myDll.dll may be in memory. Consider using Pview to detect and remove it."